# Ship by weight configuration Error

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i set ship by weight for various countries. Ship by weight configuration Error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i need to look like this     http://prnt.sc/b7anux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in reference to your chat with Arunendra.
To get a shipping charges please cross check the following things once.

1) your configuration should be like.

[image]

Make sure you have selected **India in Ship to Specific Countries** as you have selected **specific countries** in **Ship to Applicable Countries**

2) your csv should be like following one if you want to set weight >= 1 for ex.

[image]

3) Product which you are adding in a cart should have a weight equal or greater than the one which you have added in csv. in this example case its 1. so your product  or addition of weight of all products in your cart should be equal or greater than 1.

I think point 3 is the issue in your case.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: yes, its working good....

Comment: if you like the answer and able to solve your problem then you can accept and up vote it so that it will be helpful for others also.

Comment: can i use like this            IND  *  *  10-20 145

Comment: No but if you want to make it for range then i will recommend https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-1.html

Comment: how can i set weight range for zipcode. eg https://snag.gy/P7FW2G.jpg

Comment: Is this Right https://snag.gy/7sXhfd.jpg

Comment: i get error again, all are correct but i get error like http://i.imgur.com/faRTbwB.png

Comment: my excel format :  http://i.imgur.com/UlakGoa.png

Answer (score 2):

You can use this tool to generate `tablerate.csv` : https://elgentos.nl/tablerates/

[image]

Comment: can i use like this IND * * 10-20 145

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the country code in ISO-3 code, so

```
IN, *, *, 100, 10
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: ok, Let me do it

Comment: result look like http://prnt.sc/b7avzz

Comment: XL sheet :  http://prnt.sc/b7awd0

Comment: my address http://prnt.sc/b7axpk

Comment: where i can did error,,,

Comment: Make sure we are connected  ??

Comment: replace IND with IN and check again

Comment: Did you saw my all screen shots,

Comment: Ye i have seen screen shot, now what exactly you are facing ?

Comment: i did what you told, but i got the error http://prnt.sc/b7bkhp

Comment: Did you replace IND with IN ??

Comment: yes i did, same error

Comment: this is my shipping method setting    http://prnt.sc/b7booi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40158/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-arunendra).

Comment: can i use like this IND * * 10-20 145